# Executable needs to be in PATH - Running Selenium on GNURoot on Android

Tags: android, python, selenium, webdriver

Selenium installed using pip.

Trying to run below code :

```
import selenium

from selenium import webdriver

\#driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

What I get:

> python 5formscrape-selenium.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "5formscrape-selenium.py", line 5, in   driver =
>   webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
>   line 62, in **init**  self.service.start()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 81, in start  os.path.basename(self.path),
>   self.start_error_message)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver'
>   executable needs to be in PATH. Please see
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

`$PATH` contains `/usr/bin/chromedriver`

chromedriver file is in `/usr/bin` with privileges

```
sudo chmod a*x chromedriver
```

So what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

chromdriver needs to be in PATH means the directory in which it is present should be in PATH and not the whole PATH itself. Change

```
$PATH=/usr/bin/chromedriver:....
```

to

```
$PATH=/usr/bin/:....
```

Remove chromedriver, so selenium can search for `chromedriver` in `/usr/bin`

Comment: In your script add this and tell me the output `import os; import sys; import subprocess; print(sys.path); print(os.getenv('PYTHONPATH')), print(subprocess.check_output(["which", "chromedriver"]));"

Comment: ['/sdcard/3python2', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']


    None


    /usr/bin/chromedriver

Comment: as you can see your path doesn't have the `/usr/bin` directory. Make sure you are using export to export your PATH variable. `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` before running your script

Comment: I see! But using export doesn't change my PATH.

If I print it from the terminal:

# echo $PATH

/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

Comment: add this to top of your code `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/usr/bin"` and see if that helps

Comment: No, but if I print os.environ['PATH'] I get a different one than when I print sys.path
-------
/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/bin

-------

['/sdcard/3python2', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']

Comment: Sorry I mixed up a bit. I think my answer is not adding value to this question. Please update the question with the details, so others can try. I will delete this answer after few mins